# Access coordinates from a firebase database

Tags: python, coordinates, json, firebase

I want to access the coordinates from a firebase database in order to add them to my web map.

The structure of the data looks like this, and there around 12,000 sets of coordinates. [image]

In my python script I am accessing the whole body of data using

```
result = firebase.get('/ChargeDevice', None)
```

which returns a JSON.

I ultimately want to end up with a list of dictionaries storing each locations latitude and longitude. I am unsure whether I should do this through the firebase.get method or iterate over the result in python.